# Do you know any HTTP request libraries faster than aiohttp for Python?

Tags: python

Do you know any other HTTP request libraries for Python faster than aiohttp or requests-futures? I tried both but I need something faster. Are there any faster libraries or should I just move to other programming language?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, it compares different libraries and there speeds. You can also see the python libraries that are faster than requests. https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests

-hope this helps